Storybook: Updated values do not update in the UI
I need to be able to set "selectedItem" to the item that is clicked in this storybook-file. As proven by the console.log in "onItemClick", it logs out the correct item value, but the value in the  <h2\>Edit field: ${args.selectedItem}</h2\> does not update, it stays as null.
How can i fix this?
I am using version 8.2.9 of storybook, and the component itself is an angular element.
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/angular';
import { ListDetailComponent } from './list-detail.component';

const meta: Meta<ListDetailComponent> = {
  component: ListDetailComponent,
  title: 'lib/general/list-detail',
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<ListDetailComponent>;

export const Default: Story = {
  render: (args) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
      onItemClick: (item: any) => {
        console.log('item', item)
        args.selectedItem = item;
      },
    },
    template: `
      <rvn-el-list-detail>
        <ion-list slot="list">
          <rvn-el-item (click)="onItemClick('Field 1')">
            <ion-label>Field 1</ion-label>
          </rvn-el-item>
          <rvn-el-item (click)="onItemClick('Field 2')">
            <ion-label>Field 2</ion-label>
          </rvn-el-item>
          <rvn-el-item (click)="onItemClick('Field 3')">
            <ion-label>Field 3</ion-label>
          </rvn-el-item>
        </ion-list>
        <div slot="detail">
          <h2>Edit field: ${args.selectedItem}</h2>
        </div>
      </rvn-el-list-detail>
    `,
  }),
  args: {
    selectedItem: null
  },
};

I have also tried using a local variable like let localSelectedItem, but it still did not update.

I have no idea about Angular, but in plain JS a template literal is not a template. Are you using the correct Angular-specific syntax?
